# What kind of content is in the Canonical Partners repository? Is it as secure & safe as the Main repo?

Tags: software-sources

In Software Sources under the Other Software tab, there is an option of enabling "Canonical Partners" repository: software packaged by Canonical for their partners.

Do I understand correctly that this repo includes third-party created applications that by arrangement are packaged and maintained by Canonical?

Does this mean Canonical can look at the source code of these third-party applications and hence ensure the security and stability of these apps in Ubuntu, making them as secure & stable as the software in the Main repo?

Answer (score 15):

The Canonical Partner repository contains closed source third party software that doesn't cost any money. Canonical doesn't have access to the source code, they just package and test it and may provide feedback and help to the author if there are issues.

Comment: Thanks you for the info, Florian. Some link to (pseudo at least) official paper/docs would complete your opinion, please.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Maybe it would, but it would also be criticised for citing a temporal hyperlink to external content. Can't win.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what said by @Florian, you can browse the content with Synaptic Package Manager

[image: Synaptic Package Manager]

Comment: It should be noted though that Synaptic won't be installed by default anymore in 11.10.

Comment: @WarriorIng64: bad news :(

Comment: @enzotib: I don't miss it much, the new Software Center has a much nicer UI for day-to-day use, it has a cleaner interface compared to Synaptic's busy and confusing UI. I had to say, I haven't felt any need to go back to Synaptic.

Comment: @Lie I agree. Synaptic is for those situations when you need to know specifically what packages and versions you're working with, possibly because you want to uninstall older kernels without Ubuntu Tweak or you broke something. But it'll always be a `sudo apt-get install synaptic` away.