# Software & Updates; should I turn on Canonical Partners source? Source code?

Tags: repository

In Software Sources under the Other Software tab, there is an option of enabling "Canonical Partners" repository: software packaged by Canonical for their partners. Should I check "Source Code" as well? What does that mean when that's checked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kind of content is in the Canonical Partners repository? Is it as secure & safe as the Main repo?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60120/what-kind-of-content-is-in-the-canonical-partners-repository-is-it-as-secure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Canonical Partner repository contains closed source third party software that don't cost any money. Canonical doesn't have access to the source code, they just package and test it and may provide feedback and help to the author if there are issues.

For the sources, you can leave them unticked if you don't plan to do anything with the source code of software in the repositories.

Answer (score 3):

This is to activate the proprietary software that has reached an agreement with Canonical for use.

Yes you can activate it, no problem.